# Grails internalizations, add message.properties-file for new language

Tags: grails, internationalization

I have a question regarding "adding a new language" properties-file in Grails.

I tried to add a new file containing a language that wasn't put in by default - in this case I just took a language - no norwegian - and added a file named **messages_no.properties** to the i18n-folder but it won't show when I change my computer's language.

For example, Swedish se is in by default and it just works.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Did you try to navigate your application with a lang parameter, like this: http://localhost:8080/application/index?lang=no ?

Comment: Norwegian is a bit of an oddball as regards language codes, you may find you have to use `nb` and/or `nn` (Bokmål and Nynorsk respectively) instead of `no`.

Comment: @TomaszKalkosiński I'll give that a shot! But what I'm looking for is a way for it to happen like it does for Swedish or German - no /lang needed

Comment: @IanRoberts I'll give that a shot! Sounds reasonable, but how do I know this? What about other languages? For example Portugeese and Brazilia-Portugeese have different codes, any other pitfalls you might know of?

Comment: In the case of Portugal/Brazil they use the same language code but different country codes, so you can define `messages_pt` to be used by both and an additional `messages_pt_BR` for anything specific to Brazilian.  Norwegian is the odd one in that `nb` and `nn` are treated as different languages entirely rather than variants of the same language.  [This is the list that the `java.util.Locale` javadoc links to](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/English_list.php).

Comment: @IanRoberts another fine one is croatian, I tried using hr and hr_HR no nice, any experience with this?